# Trigger a flow when a folder property is updated inside 11++ Libraries

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, power-automate

I have a communication site which currently contain 12 document libraries, and each year a new library will be added, as follow:-

[image]

now i want to trigger a flow to move a folder when the folder's property named "Archived" is set to No. now i can create 12 separate workflows and add new workflow each year. But i want to be able to manage this inside one workflow is this possible? I am thinking on creating a scheduled flow which run each 1 hour >> loop through all libraries (i can add the libraries names inside an environment variable that can be updated annually) and move the related folders. As seems for automated flows they need to be linked to only one document library, any advice?